# How to create a macro that will add specific text to multiple cells when selected?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of data points that I will be going through and doing research on, filling out categories for each column associated with a row:

[image: table example]

I anticipate going through hundreds of rows doing this manually, and will have some of the same combinations over and over ("New, Ohio, Yes"). How can I set up a macro to automatically input those values into 3 cells when I select them or when I select the first cell in the row? So far I have managed to insert one value into all cells, but can't figure out how to separate the text entries:

```
 Sub AutoInsert()

 For Each c In Selection
 c.Activate
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "hello " & ActiveCell.Formula
 Next c

 End Sub
```

Comment: `Selection.Cells(1).Resize(,3).Value = Array("New", "Ohio", "Yes")`

Comment: Also, you can use [Worksheet.SelectionChange event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange) to automatically add values if the cells in the target range are selected.

Comment: Can you better explain (in words) what you want accomplishing? I mean, forgetting about selection... Do you want to fill that three values after a visual examination? Can't you, let us say, decide to place these three values for all cells in A:A being 'Item1' or 'Item3', for instance?

Comment: The provided code worked, thanks!